# What do I need to know about simplifying expressions involving Symbolic Tensors?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

I want to use *Mathematica* to show that the inner product of a vector with itself is equal to the square of its norm.

This is what I tried:

```
$Assumptions = x ∈ Vectors[3, Reals];
expr = Dot[x, x] == Norm[x]^2;

FullSimplify[expr]
(*x.x == Norm[x]^2*)

TensorReduce[expr]
(*x.x == Norm[x]^2*)
```

I had expected at least one of the last two lines to return `True`.

Why couldn't *Mathematica* simplify `expr` to `True` in this case? Are there additional assumptions I should include so that it return `True`?

Comment: One important thing to know is that not every function is supported.  I haven't used this functionality much, so I might be wrong, but I think that `Norm` is simply not (fully) supported.

Comment: The strange thing is that the documentation for `Norm` explicitly says that For vectors, `Norm[v]` is `Sqrt[v.Conjugate[v]]`.  `expr = Dot[x, x] == Sqrt[Dot[x, Conjugate[x]]]^2` does yield true, so `Norm` is not considering `x` to be a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get to what you looking for is

```
Assuming[{a, b, c} ∈ Reals, With[{x = {a, b, c}}, x.x == Norm[x]^2 // Simplify]]
```

> `True`